# C# how to specify SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty field value SPDRP_HARDWAREID

Tags: c#

I am using this function `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` in C # to query the hardware ID and to know how big a buffer to allocate for the data. But I am getting error at `SPDRP_HARDWAREID. Error message is

> "The name "SPDRP_HARDWAREID" does not exist in current context.

I have tried declaring `SPDRP_HARDWAREID` as `enum`, but it didn't worked.

Does anyone have idea?

Comment: #define SPDRP_HARDWAREID (0x00000001)  // HardwareID (R/W)

Comment: Is it allowed to use "#define" in C#. I tried it. But giving error as "cannot define/undefine preprocessor symbols. Any other way

Comment: No it isn't. I was just copying the code from the `.h` file, you need to define a constant or just pass the value (1) directly in C#. I you need more than one `SPDRP_` value in your code you should define an enumeration instead.

Comment: I tried of defining it as constant using "  public const uint  SPDRP_HARDWAREID = 1;" it didn;t worked.Here is how I am importing it  [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
            IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
           int  DeviceInfoData,
            uint Property,
           uint PropertyRegDataType,
            IntPtr PropertyBuffer, 
            uint PropertyBufferSize,
            out UInt32 RequiredSize);

Answer (score 1):

Just enter 0x00000001 and forget about the variable name if you only want to use the hardwareid function. Remember to have the other parameter types valid as well, your declaration is wrong, you should use this:

```
[DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
    IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
    ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData,
    uint Property,
    out UInt32 PropertyRegDataType,
    byte[] PropertyBuffer,
    uint PropertyBufferSize,
    out UInt32 RequiredSize
    );
```